# form field not rendering

Tags: forms, theming

i have a problem theming my user-profile-edit.php
the user name field (name) is rendering nothing, while other fields like 'mail' are working good.

```
//contents of user-profile-edit.php
<?php
print render($form['form_id']);
print render($form['form_build_id']);
print render($form['form_token']);
print render($form['account']['name']);
print render($form['account']['mail']);
?>


//contents of template.php
...
function MY_THEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'user_register' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-register',
    ),
    'user_login' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-login',
    ),
    'user_profile_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-profile-edit',
    ),
    'user_pass' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-pass',
    ),
    'user_pass_reset' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-pass-reset',
    ),
  );
}
```

in the end when I open the page mysite.com/user/1/edit I can only see the mail field.

any idea of what am I doing wrong?? or how can I render that name field so I can customize the visualization?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar problem when trying to render the Forgot Password form in a block.

Since the form builder for the form is in user.pages.inc, the solution is to load the include file at the same time you do the drupal_get_form() to retrieve the form. e.g.

module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');

If you are calling the form via a hook_menu implementation, you will need to use the 'file' and 'file path properties'.